# Rust: Reading and writing CSV performance

Tags: csv, rust

I am trying to get an indicative measure of the maximum speed with which I can read and write a 'large' CSV file using Rust.

I have a test CSV file containing 100 million identical rows:

`SomeLongStringForTesting1, SomeLongStringForTesting2`

The size of this file on disk is 4.84GB.

I have written (mostly copied!) the following code which uses the `csv: 1.1.3` crate:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    read_and_write("C:/Dev/100MillionRows.csv", "C:/Dev/100MillionRowsCopy.csv").unwrap();
}

fn read_and_write(in_file_path: &str, out_file_path: &str) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_path(in_file_path)?;

    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .from_path(out_file_path)?;

    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result?;
        wtr.write_record(record.iter())?;
    }

    wtr.flush()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Building in 'release mode' and then running with the following command:

`powershell -Command "Measure-Command {.\target\release\csv-performance.exe}"` yields `72.79 seconds, 71.01 seconds, 70.77 seconds` for three runs.

Speaking approximately, I'm seeing 10GB (combined read and write) of IO in 70 seconds, which corresponds to 142MB/S. This is approximately what Windows is reporting for disk usage in Task Manager.

This *feels* like it might be slow, for the following reasons:

`winsat disk -drive c` yields:

```
Windows System Assessment Tool
> Running: Feature Enumeration ''
> Run Time 00:00:00.00
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -ran -read'
> Run Time 00:00:01.31
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -read'
> Run Time 00:00:05.36
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -seq -write'
> Run Time 00:00:03.17
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -seq'
> Run Time 00:00:00.80
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive c -flush -ran'
> Run Time 00:00:00.73
> Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
> Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
> Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       541.88 MB/s       8.3
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   1523.74 MB/s      8.8
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  805.49 MB/s       8.3
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     0.219 ms          8.6
> Latency: 95th Percentile                     1.178 ms          8.2
> Latency: Maximum                             7.760 ms          8.2
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         0.199 ms          8.9
```

which suggests my disk (a pretty decent SSD) is capable of much more.

If I just copy the file:

`powershell -Command "Measure-Command {Copy-Item "C:/Dev/100MillionRows.csv" -Destination "C:/Dev/100MillionRowsCopy.csv"}"`

it takes `9.97 seconds, 13.85 seconds, 10.90 seconds` for three runs. Taking the average at `11.57 seconds`, I'm seeing approximately 860 MB/S of IO. This is more in the ballpark of the limitations of my disk.

Clearly when reading the CSV in my code I'm doing more work than a simple copy, but I was surprised that it would be ~6 times slower than the copy.

Would appreciate any thoughts on why this is the case and how to improve the performance of my Rust code? I'm very new to Rust so there's quite possibly something noddy there! I'm aware of the performance section of the docs https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0/csv/tutorial/index.html#performance, but these seem to be performance improvements on the order of 50%, not several hundred percent.

**Update 1**

Without modifying the code some further testing shows that the rate isn't consistent as I vary the size of the strings in the rows for 100 million rows:

`A,B` : 18 MB/S

`SomeLongStringForTesting1, SomeLongStringForTesting2` : 142 MB/S

`AAAA...(A repeated 300 times),BBBB...(B repeated 300 times)`: 279 MB/S

I'll have a go at implementing the documented improvements to see what difference it makes, and might also try profiling - any recommendations for tooling appreciated otherwise I'll just have Google.

Comment: Just pointing out that >100% reduction in execution time would mean finishing before starting. So you may have to adjust your expectations in this aspect.

Comment: Woooops! What I meant was I'm wondering if there's a way for my code to approach 6 times faster. Finishing before starting would be quite the feat!

Comment: Use a profiler to learn where your code spends its time. Everything else is just guesswork.

Comment: Why not try the tips in the performance section before dismissing them? I wrote them for a reason. If your program is still slower than you expect, then please profile it to determine the bottlenecks.

Comment: See also: https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.3/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.write_byte_record

Comment: You can try to parallelize I/O operations. Read the values in one thread and write in different another thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a pretty substantial improvement by following the performance tips in the tutorial you linked. In particular, the key is really to amortize allocations and avoid a UTF-8 check, both of which are happening in your code. Namely, your code allocates a new record in memory for each row in the CSV file. It also checks each field for valid UTF-8. Both of these have costs, but they do provide a fairly simple API that is decently fast as it is.

Additionally, one tip that isn't mentioned in the tutorial is to use `csv::Writer::write_byte_record` when possible instead of `csv::Writer::write_record`. The latter is more flexible, but the former constrains the input a bit more such that it can implement writes more efficiently in common scenarios.

Overall, making these changes is pretty easy:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    read_and_write("rows.csv", "rows-copy.csv").unwrap();
}

fn read_and_write(
    in_file_path: &str,
    out_file_path: &str,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_path(in_file_path)?;
    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .from_path(out_file_path)?;

    let mut record = csv::ByteRecord::new();
    while rdr.read_byte_record(&mut record)? {
        wtr.write_byte_record(&record)?;
    }
    wtr.flush()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Here is the timing for your code on my Linux system:

```
$ time ./target/release/csvsoperf

real    21.518
user    19.315
sys     2.189
maxmem  6 MB
faults  0
```

And here is the timing for my updated code:

```
$ time ./target/release/csvsoperf

real    12.057
user    9.924
sys     2.125
maxmem  6 MB
faults  0
```

Profiling the faster code, about 56% of the time is being spent in `csv::Reader::read_byte_record`, while about 29% of the time is being spent in `csv::Writer::write_byte_record`. This seems about right to me, and suggests your program isn't really doing anything that is additionally sub-optimal. There are no real bottlenecks outside of `csv` itself to optimize for.

> Clearly when reading the CSV in my code I'm doing more work than a simple copy, but I was surprised that it would be ~6 times slower than the copy.

It's easy to be surprised when using pathological or very constrained inputs. Your example CSV data is very simple, and indeed, there are (obviously) much faster ways to parse and write data if it follows that format. But a CSV parser doesn't know that and must be able to handle the full format, which includes dealing with escaping and quoting. The `csv` parser has had a lot of optimization work done to it, and should generally be one of the faster CSV parsers in existence. So the more appropriate comparison here should be another CSV parser. It's not surprise that a dumb copy of the data is going to be substantially faster than a parser that is doing non-trivial work on the input.